I am calling IRIS A2A end-point to fetch access token which fails Code ESRV306
I have followed the publication 5718 from IRS and after registering my app, I am trying to fetch the access token for test environment. The end-point fails with following error
{
"error_code": "ESRV306",
"error_msg": {
"error": "invalid client",
"error_description": "The given JWT for client authentication is invalid."
}
}
Any help is much appreciated, thanks!!
I have a sent a request to fetch the access token and was expecting to get the response.
internal string GenerateJWTToken(string issuer, string subject, string audience)
        {
//This is the private key generated from the certificate using openssl. 
            //"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<long-code>-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
            //pick < long - code > from above.Replace all \n with actual new line like shown below.
            string privateKey = @"MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKYwggSiAgEAAoIBAQCuxJr5bETbAhvq
I4X28UBoyGcAN91ug5rFPQ==";
            var rsaParams = ReadAsymmetricKeyParameter();
            var encoder = GetRS256JWTEncoder(rsaParams);

            var jwtHeader = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "kid", "XXXXXXX" }
                };

            var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "iss", issuer},     // Client ID
                    { "sub", subject },    // Client ID
                    { "aud", audience },    // Token endpoint (Authorization Server URL)
                    { "iat", DateTime.UtcNow }, // Token issue time
                    { "exp", DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15) }, // Token expiration time
                    { "jti", Guid.NewGuid() } // Unique token ID
                };
            //Final token
            var token = encoder.Encode(jwtHeader, payload, privateKey);

            return token;
        }
        
         private static IJwtEncoder GetRS256JWTEncoder(RSAParameters rsaParams)
         {
             var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
             csp.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
             var algorithm = new RS256Algorithm(csp, csp);
             var serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
             var urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
             var encoder = new JwtEncoder(algorithm, serializer, urlEncoder);

             return encoder;
         }
         
        public static RSAParameters ReadAsymmetricKeyParameter()
        {
            //This is the private key generated from the certificate using openssl. 
            //"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<long-code>-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
            //pick < long - code > from above.Replace all \n with actual new line like shown below.

            string pkey = @"MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKYwggSiAgEAAoIBAQCuxJr5bETbAhvq
I4X28UBoyGcAN91ug5rFPQ==";

            RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters1;
            var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pkey);
            var asymmetricKeyParameter = PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(keyBytes);
            rsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters1 = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)asymmetricKeyParameter;
            RSAParameters r = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(rsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters1);
            return r;
        }

